# Is it acceptable to remove spoiler blockquotes from questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

[We recently discussed spoilers on this site](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34/111), and the consensus was that while spoilers in titles should be avoided, spoilers in the body of questions/answers were acceptable, and therefore that spoiler blockquotes should be avoided.

If someone posts an answer that contains spoiler blockquotes, is it acceptable to remove said spoiler blockquotes?

Comment: Based on @Tsundoku's [answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1754/289), I wanna say that at least as far as my own questions and answers are concerned, I'd *welcome* it if someone removed the spoiler formatting.

Answer (score 7):

If the spoiler are excessive (90% of the answer is spoiler block), it's OK to edit them down.

If they are for things that can be reasonably argued to NOT be spoilers, it's OK to edit them out (basically, if reading the text won't actually spoil any meaningful surprises for people).

If they are of reasonable size compared to non-spoiler text, leave them alone - removing them is contrary to poster's intent.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, [spoilers are inaccessible to keyboard-only users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301971/340816). This issue was reported on Meta Stack Exchange in October 2017. Solutions have also been suggested, including [one that relies on more appropriate HTML elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371724/340816) than the `blockquote` element.

Using the current spoiler implementation **discriminates against people who can't use a mouse** (e.g. due to a motor impairment or blindness); this is a good reason for discouraging it and for editing it out when people use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be OK to remove spoiler blockquotes. There really isn't a situation where they *should* be used, per meta guidelines. Therefore they should be edited out of questions or answers.