# Should spoiler warnings be included in question titles?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

[We've previously come to the consensus that spoilers should not be included in question titles](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-assume-that-questions-about-a-book-spoil-that-book-or-should-we-use-s).

However, some community members on this site have been including *spoiler warnings* in the question title. For example, [the title of this question originally read "Did this character do this in The Physics of the Dead? [Spoiler]"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/did-this-character-do-this-in-the-physics-of-the-dead).

Out of consistancy and readability, could we agree on not using spoiler warnings in question title? We're already assuming that questions about a book spoil a book. In addition, warnings like "[spoiler]" look really ugly.

Comment: *"Did this character do this in The Physics of the Dead?"* - This is pretty much the epitome of ugly titling even *without* any superflous spoiler tags in it.

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate because [we've already come to the consensus that spoilers should not be contained in titles](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-assume-that-questions-about-a-book-spoil-that-book-or-should-we-use-s). There's nothing new to discuss here.

Comment: @Hamlet this is not the same issue, but is not apparent anymore because of the new title of the question linked to..

Comment: @VicAche oh, OK, I see what you mean. Sorry about that, this was my fault. I'll reopen the question now.

Comment: @Hamlet I was insisting because I wrote this meta post to open the discussion on formatting here. For a literature SE, we have terrible formatting habits!

Comment: @VicAche this was a good question and I'm glad you asked it. I closed it because I was dumb and had no idea what I was doing. Sorry about that, and thank you for starting this important discussion!

Answer (score 6):

(based on the linked meta discussion) If you see someone added [spoilers] to the title - edit it out. If someone wants to put a spoiler warning in the body, that's fine, but don't include stuff like that in the title - just make sure your title doesn't contain any actual spoilers.

Comment: But don't go overboard with “non-spoliy” titles. “Did this character do this” is not a useful title.

Comment: @Gilles - yes; I'd recommend having the character's name but not the action.

Comment: @Gilles agreed, the title should provide enough info to at least, find the question with no precise memory of its phrasing